# Arshaw FullCalendar: suppress top row (date) on agendaDay view

Tags: fullcalendar

Arshaw FullCalendar displays the current date in agendaDay view even if I set all headers off. I would like the entire th of that table to disappear. How do I do that in agendaDay view?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',  
    header: {
        left: 'false',
        center: 'false',
        right: 'false'
    },
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vm3vhx7L/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Set header itself to false:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',  
    header: false
});
```

Comment: Sadly, this does not work. When I try that the day and date still show at the top row, or technically, table header. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7chu4hsc/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no option to remove the text and, even if you set all header options to an empty string, it still displays the day, you can use [`viewRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/) to hide the text.

So, after the calendar has been render, we will find the `fc-day-header` th and set html to an empty string. See a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/od4Le2er/). This code works for **Fullcalendar 2.***.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: '',
        right: ''
    },
    viewRender: function(view, element) {
        element.find('.fc-day-header').html('');
    }
});
```

This will keep the `th`, but will have an height of 0. If you want to remove the entire `thead`, you could use `element.find('.fc-day-header').parents('table:first').parents('thead').remove()`

If you want to use **Fullcalendar 1.6.3/1.6.4** the classnames are a bit different, and you should use

```
element.find(".fc-col0.fc-widget-header").html('');
```

Check the [working fiddle using 1.6.4](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/vm3vhx7L/2/):

**Before 1.6.3**

You are using FullCalendar 1.5.3 in your fiddle. This is a really old release and I advice you to update it. I haven't looked for a solution because you didn't specify that requirement. However the one provided won't work, since `eventRender` was introduced in Fullcalendar 1.6.3.